I'm in Ireland already. I came with a student visa and can't get employment without a permit
After college in Ireland, I was given a stamp 1G, but I was still working with the agency thinking my employer could get me an employment permit. So I did not bother searching for full time employment. Now my stamp 1G is gone and I have been given stamp 1 with the condition that my employer should apply for an employment permit on my behalf. However, I have been going for interviews with job offers. All the employers have refused to apply for an employment permit. What might be the problem please?

Perhaps the employers can fill the role with a candidate who already has a work permit, so don’t want the bother and time delay of applying for a new one for you. Or the type of work is ineligible for an employment permit. What did the employers say when you asked them why?

Ireland is a member of the EU. This means that they have to give equal weight to Irish and EU citizens who apply for jobs. They must be considered before any non-EU citizens. The employer will have to show that they couldn't find a EU (and probably UK citizens) to fill the role, before they can offer it to you.

There are nine types of work permits  in Ireland so the answer may depend on the type of employment you’re seeking. Most likely it is because you and/or the prospective employers do not meet the relevant eligibility criteria.
For example, to be eligible for the general employment permit, an employer must:

Be registered with the Companies Registration Office, and have a valid tax registration number;
Have been trading for at least 12 months preceding the date of application;
Have a satisfactory record of compliance with employment legislation;
Be able to demonstrate a genuine need for the position in question;
Be able to provide evidence of advertising the position in Ireland; and
Pay the prescribed wage for the position.
Meet any sector-specific eligibility criteria that may apply.

Importantly, as @CSM commented, the employer must also demonstrate that they cannot fill the position with a suitably qualified EEA national.
The employee must:

Be a non-EEA national;
Possess the necessary qualifications and skills for the position;
Have at least one year’s relevant work experience; and
Meet the English language requirements.
The job salary must be above the minimum threshold set by the Ministry for Business, Enterprise, and Innovation. As of January 2024, the minimum threshold for a General Employment Permit is €34,000 per year.
The job must not be on the Ineligible List of Occupations.


CSEP application, I presume that's the case, is a long and costly process especially for a small business. This year (2024 AD) is an economical slowdown for Ireland with many corporations applying hire freeze. But those ones who still have open positions prefer to hire workers with existing working rights.
